# Regex ignores certain characters

Tags: .net, regex, math

I'm making a .NET program that parses simple arithmetic, and I use this Regex:

```
Regex Part = new Regex("([0-9]+)(\\+|\\-|\\/|\\*)([0-9]+)");
```

This ignores certain characters. Let's say I have this, for example:

```
4+5*2
```

The Regex splits it into 2 parts - `4+` and `*2` - totally ignoring the 5 that's there.

I want it to split it into `4+5` and `5*2` - how do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just put your regex inside a positive lookahead in-order to achieve overlapping matches.

```
@"(?=(\b\d+[-+/*]\d+\b))"
```

Then get the parts you want from group index 1. Normally regex won't do overlapping matches by default, you have to put your regex inside a capturing group and then put that capturing group inside a positive lookahead to get the overlapping matches. `\d+` should match one or more digit characters.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/wN9jS6/3)

Comment: Thank you very much! I can accept your answer in 8 minutes, so I'll wait and accept.

Can you please explain shortly why this works? What does the question sign do and what do the `\d+`s do? EDIT: Doesn't seem to work in .NET. 2 results but the Value property is empty ("").

Comment: try `value[1]` with this regex `"(?=(\\d+[-+/*]\\d+))"`

Comment: @AlanMoore Good Catch, `(?=(\b\d+[-+/*]\d+\b))`